# Custom setting moveAll/removeAll icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using **[Bootstrap Dual Listbox](https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)** plugin with **[Font Awesome 4.7.0](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/)**.

I want to customize the `"Move all"` and `"Remove all"` button icons with a single `'»'` and `'«'`. However, these button icons are rendering incorrectly for me.

```js
var dualListContainer = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox({

  // default text
  moveAllLabel: 'Move all',
  removeAllLabel: 'Remove all',
});


$(function() {
  var customSettings = $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1"]').bootstrapDualListbox('getContainer');
  customSettings.find('.moveall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right');
  customSettings.find('.removeall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-left');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-duallistbox@3.0.6/dist/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-duallistbox@3.0.6/dist/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
      <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
      <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
      <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
      <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added this jQuery just below where I created the bootstrapDualListBox:

```
$(function() {
  var customSettings = $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1"]').bootstrapDualListbox('getContainer');
  customSettings.find('.moveall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right');
  customSettings.find('.removeall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-left');
});
```

Can this be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that there are two icons being added to  the buttons, and you only want one to show up. To achieve this, you can simply remove the secondary icon by adding `.next().remove()` after adding the new classes.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var dualListContainer = $('[name=duallistbox_demo1]').bootstrapDualListbox({

  // default text
  moveAllLabel: 'Move all',
  removeAllLabel: 'Remove all',
});

$(function() {
  var customSettings = $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1"]').bootstrapDualListbox('getContainer');
  customSettings.find('.moveall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right').next().remove();
  customSettings.find('.removeall i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-angle-double-left').next().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-duallistbox@3.0.6/dist/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-duallistbox@3.0.6/dist/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
      <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
      <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
      <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
      <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve this problem with the help of css:

```
<style>
    .buttons > .btn i + i{
         display:none;
    }
</style>
```